# Via Jenkins send deployment email

Tags: jenkins

I am newly learning jenkins, I have some idea in my hand, some one please assist it is possible or not.

I am from part of deployment team, before start the deployment i need to send the outage notification to testing team and development team manually using outlook mail box.

Now thing is i have planed to send the outage via jenkins, with Parameterized Build options:

[Via Jenkins send email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D38Q.png)

From address and to recipients address will be keep on change based on the deployment environment.

Can you please some one help me on this ?

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Add a `choice/string parameter` to your job for user to input deployment env

[image]

**2)** Add a `Execute shell` build step and with following shell to output the value of 'From Address', 'To recipients' etc to a properties style file according to user inputed Env_Name

Note: if your jenkins slave is Windows, please choose a `Execute Windows batch command` and change the script accordingly

[image]

**3)** Add a `Inject environment variables` build step 
to inject enviroment varabiles for post actions by specifying the file path genegated at above step 2)

[image]

**4)** Add a `Editale Email Notification` Post Build Action with following input

[image]

Comment: Hi Yong, I am getting below error on this setup
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Email was triggered for: Failure - Any
Sending email for trigger: Failure - Any
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
Finished: FAILURE